# Quick sort function works only if last value is the largest

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct

I'm trying to practice using Quick Sort in C. My program is a simple array of structs that takes in command line args (name1 age 1 name2 age2...etc) and outputs said ages in descending order.

It works correctly ONLY if the last age inputted is the largest. Other than that I either get no output or Seg Fault 11. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NameLen 80
void print_struct();

struct people
{
char name [NameLen + 1];
int age;
}; //defining a structure//

typedef struct people PERSON;
void quicksort(struct people list[],int,int);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])

{
int i,j;
j = 0;
int l = ((argc/2)-1);


struct people list[l]; //maximum size of array of structs


   if (argc %2 == 0) //if the number of arguments is an even number
{

printf("Invalid Arguments!\n");
printf("Usage : ./hw5 name1 age1 name2 age2 ... "); //print error message and correct program usage
    exit(0);
}

printf("You have entered %d persons(s) into the program \n",(argc/2));

for (i=1; i < argc; i+=2)

{
    strcpy(list[j].name, argv[i]);
    list[j].age = atoi(argv[i+1]);
    if(list[j].age == 0)
    {
        printf("...Invalid age <=0. Try again.\n");

        exit(0);
    }
    j++;

}
   printf("Unsorted Names: \n");
    print_struct(&list,argc);

printf ("Sorted by Age: \n");
quicksort(list,0 ,j);
for(i=0;i<j;i++){
  printf("Name : %s| Age : %d\n", list[i].name, list[i].age);}//possible error here?

//Quicksort Function
```

Comment: Maintaining a consistent code style will definitely improve readability.

Comment: Thanks @Kupiakos! This is my second time posting so I will continue to work on it!

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding 1) consistently indent the code 2) use consistent vertical spacing 3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  It is missing the end of function`main()`.

Comment: this line, which calculates the size of the `list[]` array: `int l = ((argc/2)-1);` is not correct.  This is an integer divide.  If `argc` is 7, the the resulting value for `l` should be 3  however, the calculation results in 2.  Suggest removing the `-1` from the expression  Otherwise the code is accessing beyond the end of the `list[]` array, which results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: in the code block that checking if an age of 0 was entered,  the statement: `exit(0);` is not correct.  the returned value of 0 indicates success when in reality the code, at that point, should be returning a error indication.  Suggest: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`   Note `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are both defined in `stdlib.h`   Also, error messages should be output to `stderr`, so the call to `printf()` in that code block should be: `fprintf( stderr, "...Invalid age <=0. Try again.\n" );`

Comment: printing out the value of `l` rather than `argc/2` would have told you the root problem with the program.

Comment: the code already has a function: `print_struct()`, so why the loop at the end?  just call the function again to print the sorted list[] array.

Comment: in C, when referencing the name of an array, it degrades to the address of the first byte of the array, so this line: `print_struct(&list,argc);` is not correct.  Suggest: `print_struct( list, l );`   Then modify the function: `print_struct()` to expect the second parameter to be the actual number of elements in the `list[]` array.

Comment: this prototype: `void print_struct();` is a very poor method as it does not indicate what the types of the parameters are, so the compiler cannot check those parameters.  Suggest: `void print_struct(  PERSON *, int );`  and place the prototype AFTER the definition of the `typedef` that defines `PERSON`

Comment: in general, when `#define`ing a value, wrap the value in parens.  Standard practice is to write macro names in ALL CAPS with root words separated by an underscore  as in: `#define NAME_LEN (80)`

Comment: regarding this line: `strcpy(list[j].name, argv[i]);`  There is nothing stopping the user of the program writing a name that is greater than 80 characters.  Suggest using: `memset( list[i].name, '\0', NAME_LEN+1); strncpy( list[j].name, argv[i], NAME_LEN );`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the problem is the value of j. Is j the length of list? Or the length of list - 1?

It seems like this would be what you would want:
j = length of list

```
printf ("Sorted by Age: \n");
quicksort(list,0 ,j-1);
for(i=0;i<j;i++){
  printf("Name : %s| Age : %d\n", list[i].name, list[i].age);}
```

Comment: I tried that before as well! No Luck. Still getting that Seg Fault!

Comment: In that case, can you share more of your code? I haven't been able to reproduce the error.

Comment: Sure thing! I'll post it all below! Thanks in advance @MAS

Comment: Edited above... Sorry if it's a lot of code! I'm just simply AT A LOSS! @MAS

Comment: Why do you does l = ((argc/2)-1) ? Don't you want l = argc/2? @QuesionableCode

Answer (score 0):

The quicksort function is fine.  The issue is that you're calling it wrong:

```
quicksort(list,0 ,j);
```

The values you're passing in for `first` and `last` represent the index of the first and last elements.  As evident from how you use `j` to loop through the elements, `j` is the number of elements.  That means that the last element has index `j-1`.

So you're passing a value for `last` that is one element past the end of the array.  When you then try to read/write this bogus element, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in your case (fortunately) leads to a segfault.

Pass in the actual index of the last element (i.e. one less than the size) and it runs successfully.

```
quicksort(list,0 ,j - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are incorrect:

```
    while(list[i].age<=list[pivot].age&&i<last)
        i++;
```

It is possible for this loop to end with `i == last`, which is bad because you attempt to swap the value, which would be out of scope of the array.

```
    while(list[j].age>list[pivot].age)
        j--;
```

Here, since `j` starts as `last`, you start right off with reading outside of the array.

One possible remedy is to move `j` backwards first, then test (`do`-`while` style). Then, increment `i`, testing against the decremented `j`.

```
    do --j; while(list[j].age>list[pivot].age);
    do ++i; while(list[i].age<=list[pivot].age&&i<j);
```

Comment: Thank you @jxh I implied your strategy, which solves the Seg Fault problem, but however, it still refuses to sort correctly. :(

Answer (score 0):

I made the code a little bit simple (changed the array of chars to just a char to make it more simple as possible).
My thoughts are that when you call:

```
quicksort(list,0 ,j);
```

What you should call is:

```
quicksort(list,0 ,j-1);
```

Because the last parameter must be the array lenght minus 1, the last position.

I got no seg fault, when running your code, or the one I modified, if it is possible, double check the strings you are using as input.

Here is "my" vesion of the code.

Hope it helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NameLen 80
void print_struct();

struct people
{
    char name;
    int age;
}; //defining a structure//

typedef struct people PERSON;
void quicksort(struct people list[],int,int);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i,j;
    j = 10;
    struct people list[10]; //maximum size of array of structs

    for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        list[i].name = 'a';
        list[i].age = 10-i;
    }

    printf("Unsorted Names: \n");
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        printf("Name : %c| Age : %d\n", list[i].name, list[i].age);}//possible error here?

    printf ("Sorted by Age: \n");
    quicksort(list,0 ,j-1);
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        printf("Name : %c| Age : %d\n", list[i].name, list[i].age);}//possible error here?
}

void quicksort(struct people list[],int first,int last)
{
  struct people temp;
  int i,j,pivot;

  if(first<last){
        pivot=first;
        i=first;
        j=last;

        while(i<j)
        {
            while(list[i].age<=list[pivot].age&&i<last)
                i++;
            while(list[j].age>list[pivot].age)
                j--;
            if(i<j){
                temp=list[i];
                list[i]=list[j];
                list[j]=temp;
            }
        }

    temp=list[pivot];
    list[pivot]=list[j];
    list[j]=temp;
    quicksort(list,first,j-1);
    quicksort(list,j+1,last);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after applying all the comments, this is the resulting code, which cleanly compiles, but will not link due to the two missing functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_LEN (80)


struct people
{
    char name [NAME_LEN + 1];
    int age;
}; //defining a structure//

typedef struct people PERSON;

// print_struct( ptrToList, numElements )
void print_struct( PERSON *, int );

// quicksort( ptrToList, firstOffset, numElements )
void quicksort(struct people list[],int,int);


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //int i,j;
    //j = 0;
    //int l = ((argc/2)-1);
    int l = argc/2;

    struct people list[l]; //maximum size of array of structs

    if (argc %2 == 0) //if the number of arguments is an even number
    {
        //printf("Invalid Arguments!\n");
        fprintf( stderr, "Invalid Arguments!\n" );

        //printf("Usage : ./hw5 name1 age1 name2 age2 ... "); //print error message and correct program usage
        fprintf( stderr, "Usage : %s name1 age1 name2 age2 ... ", argv[0]);

        // exit(0);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //printf("You have entered %d persons(s) into the program \n",(argc/2));
    printf("You have entered %d persons(s) into the program \n", l);

    //for (int i=1; i < argc; i+=2)
    for (int i=1, j=0; j < l; i+=2, j++)
    {
        //strcpy(list[j].name, argv[i]);
        memset( list[i].name, '\0', NAME_LEN+1);
        strncpy( list[j].name, argv[i], NAME_LEN );
        list[j].age = atoi(argv[i+1]);

        if(list[j].age == 0)
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "...Invalid age <=0. Try again.\n");

            //exit(0);
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        //j++;
    }

    printf("Unsorted Names: \n");
    //print_struct(&list,argc);
    print_struct( list, l );

    //printf ("Sorted by Age: \n");
    //quicksort(list,0 ,j);
    quicksort( list, 0, l ); 

    printf ("Sorted by Age: \n");
    // //for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    //for( int i=0; i<l; i++ )
    //{
    //  printf("Name : %s| Age : %d\n", list[i].name, list[i].age);
    //}//possible error here?
    //}
    print_struct( list, l);
} // end function: main


//Quicksort Function
```